# How to force moq to call the constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I have a unit test to verify that an object (say `Foo`) will call certain method (say `Bar`) when an event is fired with certain eventArgs. To mock the said method, I use virtual and stub the `Foo` class

```
Mock<Foo> stubbedFoo = new Mock<Foo>(mockEventProvider);

mockEventProvider.Raise( x => x.MyEvent += null, myEventArgs ) //fire the event
stubbedFoo.Verify(foo => foo.Bar()); verify Bar is called as a result
```

However, the above failed, Bar will not be called, apparently because the Foo object is not event constructed. However if I add a line like below:

```
Mock<Foo> stubbedFoo = new Mock<Foo>(mockEventProvider);
var workAround = stubbedFoo.Object //adding this workaround will work
mockEventProvider.Raise( x => x.MyEvent += null, myEventArgs ) //fire the event
stubbedFoo.Verify(foo => foo.Bar()); verify Bar is called as a result
```

It will work, because calling get on .Object apparently forces mock to construct the object. Is there a more elegant solution than adding this line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can.  I checked out the [moq source](http://code.google.com/p/moq/source/checkout) and poked through it and it doesn't look like the proxy intercepter from [castle](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) is actually created until you call `.Object`. Look at this trace:

```
public object Object
{
    get { return this.GetObject(); }
}

private object GetObject()
{
    var value = this.OnGetObject();
    this.isInitialized = true;
    return value;
}
```

Followed by

```
protected override object OnGetObject()
{
    if (this.instance == null)
    {
        this.InitializeInstance();
    }

    return this.instance;
}
```

Which does this:

```
private void InitializeInstance()
{
    PexProtector.Invoke(() =>
    {
        this.instance = proxyFactory.CreateProxy<T>(
            this.Interceptor,
            this.ImplementedInterfaces.ToArray(),
            this.constructorArguments);
    });
}
```

ProxyFactory actually creates the object and wraps it in a proxy

```
public T CreateProxy<T>(ICallInterceptor interceptor, Type[] interfaces, object[] arguments)
{
    var mockType = typeof(T);

    if (mockType.IsInterface)
    {
        return (T)generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget(mockType, interfaces, new Interceptor(interceptor));
    }

    try
    {
        return (T)generator.CreateClassProxy(mockType, interfaces, new ProxyGenerationOptions(), arguments, new Interceptor(interceptor));
    }
    catch (TypeLoadException e)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Resources.InvalidMockClass, e);
    }
    catch (MissingMethodException e)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Resources.ConstructorNotFound, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see.. do you think this is a flaw in moq?

Comment: I'd say this was probably an intentional decision, but moq is open source so you can change it if you want